# How to make a constructor for a pointer member?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working on some pointer practice in my C++ class and have gotten stuck working on problem, say I have a class like this :

```
    class foo 
    {
     public:
       foo(char *inputWord = "");  // Default parameter constructor
     private:
        char * word; 
        int wordSize; // length of word
    };
```

and in main I have :

```
int main()
{
  foo baz("t");
  foo bar("test");
  return 0;
}
```

> How would I make an implementation for this constructor?
>
> ---
>
> So far I know that to initialize wordSize I could just do :

```
foo::foo()
{
  wordSize = strlen(inputWord);
}
```

But I don't understand how to initialize the char *word. 
I've tried the following:

- strcpy(word,strlen);
- for(int i =0; i< wordSize; i++)
     word[i] = inputWord[i];
- int count = 0;
  while(count < wordSize+1)
  {
     inputWord = word;
     inputWord++;
  }

None of the above methods work. I even tried using `memcpy()` and `memmove()` but I just got stuck.

Has anyone dealt with this before and could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please make your own life easier by not using pointers for string, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: If you *still* want to use pointers, think about where `foo::word` *points* in the constructor, i.e. *nowhere*.

Comment: Lastly, the literal (constant) string `""` will give you a pointer to a constant array containing *one* character, the string terminator character `'\0'`. If you want the pointer argument to be "no string" you should make it point to a null pointer, i.e. `nullptr` (or possibly `0`). And of course have checks for that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I can't just remove a term from the code. The assignment is to modify the code that I have I changed some variable names for simplicity but I can't just change the types. I don't want to use pointers but I NEED to understand them. And yes your right about `word` that is the problem I am having and why I asked the question

Comment: I would say you need to learn how to use new.

Comment: People that are downvoting me. Please don't project your hatred of pointers onto me I didn't make this class or C++ I'm just an undergrad trying to learn it. If there is something wrong with my question please tell me and I will format it.

Comment: @jussij `new` was not included in the source file provided. The class has the functions and members just as I have listed them. I cannot change the type of the member variables

Comment: You have a ctor defined as follows `foo(char *inputWord = "")` and the member of the class is defined as `char * word;`. With those constraints and without an understanding new (or an understanding of std::string as someone else pointed out) you will just be writing code that is prone to failure. Here is a hint. Who owns the 'char *inputWord` passed in to the ctor? By using new (or std::string) you remove that uncertainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `strcpy` just after having allocate memory:

```
Foo(char *inputWord) {
  if (inputWord==nullptr) { // manage null pointer
    wordSize=0;
    word=nullptr;
    return;
  }
  wordSize = strlen(inputWord); // store string length
  word = new char[wordSize+1];  // allocate enough memory to store the original C-style string
  strcpy(word,inputWord);       // copy the original into destination
}
```

This is C-style, but you'd better use `string`s in C++:

```
class Foo {
  private:
    string word;
  public:
    Foo(const string &input) : word(input) {} // initialize word with inputWord (let C++ string type do all the tricky parts)
};
```

C++ `string` type is able to manage correctly (de)allocations, length, etc.

Comment: I think the point of the assignment is to get us to learn that. A big talking point in lecture is understanding more about algorithm complexity, big-o and other things that make a program efficient. I've never created a pointer then made it a dynamic array in a function before.Or seen it done in code so that is mindblowing to me right now. I can't wait to try it when I get home. I'll accept your answer if I can get it to work. Also I don't know C at all. C++ is my first programming language and I'm also trying to pick up html5. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction! :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay but your code definitely helped me out. I am working with developing accessor and mutator member function for that class. A follow-up question. I received 4 downvotes for this questions. Do you have any recommendations so that I don't almost get downvoted into oblivion in the future?

Comment: Don't bother about it, most of them are due to the fact that the readers are bored with "simple" questions... Emotional reaction... If you ask for very complex deep hard technical detail about something, then you will get upvotes, even if the reader doesn't understand a word about it.